# Can I claim compensation for loss of earnings due to work accident in Australia?

Tags: employment, australia, injury

I was working in a hair salon in Australia and fell backwards.  I tore my rotator cuff and have slipped disc. I had surgery on shoulder when got back to UK. Can I claim for loss of earnings, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

All employees in Australia are covered by state-based Worker’s Compensation insurance. [This](https://www.sira.nsw.gov.au/resources-library/workers-compensation-resources/publications/workers-and-claims/injured-at-work-guide) is the workers’ guide for NSW.

In theory, your loss of income and medical expenses should be claimable. However, as it seems that you did not follow the required procedures, in practice, you may find it a bureaucratic nightmare.

First, you needed to have been seen by a registered Australian doctor and receive a Workers Compensation certificate to get the ball rolling. Do you have evidence that the injury occurred at work?

Second, benefits are suspended if you leave the country. There may be exemptions for temporary workers but I am unaware of them.

Contact the authority responsible for workers compensation in the state you were injured.